# Which timer does Arduino Nano use for each PWM pin?

Tags: arduino-nano, pwm, timers

I'm unable to find which Timer controls each PWM pin (3, 5, 6, 9, 10 and 11) in an Arduino Nano Board (ATmega328).
Any guesses?

Thanks in advance,

Eduardo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good pinmapping picture of the Nano : [www.pighixxx.com/test/portfolio-items/nano/](http://www.pighixxx.com/test/portfolio-items/nano/)

A timer has sometimes two outputs, A and B. The pins with OC0A and OC0B are timer outputs of Timer0. OC1A and OC1B are Timer1, OC2 and OC2B are Timer2.

Everything is also in the datasheet of the ATmega328P, but that picture is a lot easier.